# Multiple Custom Prototype Cells in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

I have been searching on the internet for about two days now, but I can't seem to understand how this works.

I have two video cells FeaturedVideoCell and YouTubeVideoCell. There is going to only be one FeaturedVideoCell and multiple YouTubeVideoCells...

I'm running a data fetch algorithm and will grab the data that fills both cells and then populate the cells by reloading the table data. Each cell with populate with a certain number of rows based on a count of objects in a corresponding array.

I have it working for the YouTubeVideoCells, but can't seem to get the second to FeaturedCell to work. I either get an error or it doesn't load my first cell. I have tried multiple solutions from this site and others, and am getting quite frustrated. Does anyone know the proper implementation technique for this? I'm using storyboarding as well...

```
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(isFiltered)
{
    return filteredyoutuberArray.count;
}
else
{
    return youtuberArray.count;
}
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"videoCell";
YouTubeVideoCell *cell = nil;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[YouTubeVideoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

YouTubeVideoObj* tempVideo = [[YouTubeVideoObj alloc] init];
if(isFiltered == TRUE)
{
    tempVideo = [filteredyoutuberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else
{
    tempVideo = [youtuberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

cell.YouTuberName.text = tempVideo.YouTuberName;
cell.totalUploadViews.text = tempVideo.totalUploadViews;
cell.subscribers.text = tempVideo.subscribers;
cell.videoCount.text = tempVideo.videoCount;
cell.orderNum.text = tempVideo.orderNum;
cell.profile.image = tempVideo.profile;

[cell setNeedsLayout];
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
[cell prepareForReuse];

return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
```

Comment: a) can you show some relevant code please ?

Comment: b) im confused as to how your cell/row matching works based on what you said, but i'll wait to see the code

Comment: @jesses.co.tt I apologize!!! This is my tableviewcontroller code I have working with one uitableviewcell, not two.

Comment: Where do you want the FeaturedVideoCell to appear? Do you want it to be the first row? Also, the code in numberOfRows doesn't match what you said you want to do -- you're returning the count of two different arrays but you said you only want one FeaturedVideoCell. Shouldn't you be returning 1 for one or the cases?

Answer (score 1):

Ah. I think I know what is going on... do you have two different UITables? 
If so, the same method cellForRowAtIndexPath will fire regardless of which cell/table is being selected/touched/called/filled etc.

IF this IS your issue, try detecting WHICH table is currently calling the method, then do the appropriate stuff in each case. Eg:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// blah blah cell stuff 

if(tableView == YouTubeTable) {
  // assign relevant data to relevant table based on relevant row
}
else if (tableView == FeaturedTable) {
  // ditto but with different relevance
}

}
```

???

Comment: No, this is all inside of one UITableViewController. I only have one tableview, two different uitableviewcells that present different things.

Comment: The first cell will be static, the second cell with take in an array of objects, and will multiply based on the amount of objects in that array.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe the issue is the potentially mix of static/dynamic ? I would try to make them dynamic/reuseable instead of static, and just always pin the Featured Cell to indexPath 0, then base your YouTuber ones off of the rest of the array ?

Comment: I have tried that actually, maybe I coded it incorrectly. I'm not quite sure. Could I potentially make them both dynamic?

Comment: well afaik (not in front of xcode right now) you HAVE to set them all to be one or the other... on a per table basis

Answer (score 0):

Rather than taking 2 individual cells, 
take 2 sections,

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
  return 2; // 2 sections
  }
```

1 for the static cells and the other section for the dynamic cell elements.
Its much more subtle

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented it, like if you set isFilter's value TRUE, the table will show filteredyoutuberArray cells and if isFilter's value FALSE, the table will show youtuberArray cells. So what do you want to show, Both type of cells in tableView? if so,

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: filteredyoutuberArray];
[array addObjectsFromArray: youtuberArray];

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
         return filteredyoutuberArray.count+youtuberArray.count;
   }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"videoCell";
    YouTubeVideoCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[YouTubeVideoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    YouTubeVideoObj* tempVideo = [[YouTubeVideoObj alloc] init];
    tempVideo = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.YouTuberName.text = tempVideo.YouTuberName;
    cell.totalUploadViews.text = tempVideo.totalUploadViews;
    cell.subscribers.text = tempVideo.subscribers;
    cell.videoCount.text = tempVideo.videoCount;
    cell.orderNum.text = tempVideo.orderNum;
    cell.profile.image = tempVideo.profile;
   [cell prepareForReuse];

   return cell;
```

}

If you will take two sections, you have to check the section and take the array accordingly to fetch object.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got what's your problem actually, but I think I should tell you following code is very bad coding, especially, `[cell prepareForReuse];` is called by tableView before `cellForRow:`, do this will cause bug. And  `[cell setNeedsLayout];` `[cell setNeedsDisplay];` should not be called by yourself in `cellForRow:` in most cases.

```
[cell setNeedsLayout];
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
[cell prepareForReuse];
```